# What is the best approach to Pixel Art?

Tags: texturing, uv, pixel-art

So, i'm making blocky models of the weapons, and noticed that it takes a lot of time to map the texture (and make a texture itself!) if there a lot of parts / faces of the gun. What the best approach to do pixel art texturing here? (See the demo GIF after screenshots)
[image][image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think anyone can give an answer besides random ideas, which isn't what this Q&A forum is meant for.  All you show is that you have a model with a texture, and you are unhappy about the length and complexity of process to get there, but we don't know what was your process nor what you are looking for instead. There isn't a magical recipe for making anything, so nobody can honestly give you any "best approach". You need to give more details about all that.